# Microsoft Build Version : Combine MajorRevision and MinorRevision into Revision

Tags: c#, revision

I have a 5 part build version (ex 1.9.0.0.1) which I want to convert to 4 part. I'm using the following code to combine the major and minor revisions.

`new Version(major, minor, build, majorRevision | (minorRevision << 16)`

This results in 1.9.0.65536 but the maximum value allowed for the Revision is 65535. What is the correct formulae to combine the major and minor revisions?

Thanks

Comment: Why not using a 3 part build version? Because `new Version(major, minor, build)` does already include both major and minor build revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only could you just use a three part version number (because it does contain both, minor and major revision number):

```
new Version(major, minor, build)
```

but you could also use the [Version Constructor (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0hf9t2e(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string version = major + "." + minor + "." + build + "." + (majorRevision | (minorRevision << 16));
var ver = new Version(version);
```

But it will not remove the error, because it will automatically parse the splitted string to integers. So I suggest using a three part version...

You could than access your Version using the [`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) and create your own Version string:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string myVersion = assembly.GetName().Version + ".";
int major = int.Parse(myVersion.Split('.')[0]); // Get the major version number
int minor = int.Parse(myVersion.Split('.')[1]); // Get the minor version number
myVersion += (major | (minor << 16)) + ""; // Append the rest
```

There are also great examples on the documentation of [Version.Revision Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.revision(v=vs.110).aspx)! They even described an answer to your question:

```
Version interim = new Version(2, 4, 1128, (100 << 16) + 2);

// major.minor.build.majRev/minRev = 2.4.1128.100/2
```

But still think about if it really fits your use case!